# Issue with Window.parent.postMessage Ack

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener

I am using `window.parent.postMessage` to communicate with a client. The client at the moment can only handle one record at a time. I have to send them one record, wait for a response, send them a second record. The second order is never sent because my flag is always null event though it's being set in the event listener.

**This is my send message Method:**

```
   var SendMessage = function (Record, count, readyForNextRecord) {
    if (Record.length > 0) {
        var response = sessionStorage.getItem("response");;
        if (readyForNextRecord === true) {
            var url = (window.location != window.parent.location) ? document.referrer : document.location;
            window.parent.postMessage(Record[count], url);
            count++;
        }
       if(count < Record.length){
         if (response == null) {
            interval =   window.setInterval(SendMessage(Record, count, false), 100)
          } else {
              response = null;
              clearInterval(interval);
             window.setTimeout(SendMessage(Record, count, true), 100);
          }
    }
}
```

**The event listener**

```
window.addEventListener("message", ReceiveMessage, false);

var ReceiveMessage = function (event) {
    for (var val in event.data) {
        var message = event.data[val];
        switch (message.toString().toLowerCase()) {
            case "success":
                sessionStorage.setItem("response", true);
                break;
            case "failure":
                sessionStorage.setItem("response", false);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**In the end, I reached the maximum call stack size**:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: `window.setInterval(SendMessage(Record, count, true), 100);` is this part correct? Or did you mean to use setTimeout again? Since you never clear that interval again, you create an infinite loop, no matter if response is null or not.

Comment: I do want to use the setInterval as long as there are more records. I updated the script to cancel the inverval and check for additional records.

Comment: Then you should use setTimeout, since you use a recursive function. You mimic setInterval by having SendMessage calls itsself again, so using an interval here and cancelling the prev interval each time SendMessage is called, is the same as using setTimeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did as @Shilly suggested, and it's been working as expected. I changed this line of code below to use

**I changed this line of code**

```
interval =   window.setInterval(SendMessage(Record, count, false), 100)
```

To

```
 window.setTimeout(SendMessage(Record, count, false), 200);
```